# get array of files in uploads dir

Tags: uploads

We created a frontend user profile, where the user can upload files to a special directory in wp-content/uploads/

The upload is done with a plugin called ultimate member (there it will create a special directory for every userupload (directoryname = user ID).

For example, we want to have the ability, that the user can upload mp3 tracks to his profile and the can be played there...

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$upload_to = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/ultimatemember/' . $user_id;
// echo $upload_to;
echo list_files( $upload_to );
```

List Files creates an error where it says function does not exist, does anyone has another idea how to get those files`?

For security reasons, it would be nice if someone can tell me the way which is the safest...

I also tried glob(), but its returning an empty array...

```
  // Abfragen der aktuellen Profil ID
  $profile_id = um_profile_id();
  um_fetch_user( $profile_id );


$url = get_home_url() . '/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/' . $profile_id .'/';
$files = glob( $url . '*' );

// print_r($files);

foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    $str = $file . basename( $file );
    echo $str;
    echo do_shortcode('[audio src="' . $str . '"]');
}
```

Comment: How are files being uploaded to the folder? Are you sure the path you're passing is correct? And have you confirmed that MP3 files actually make it to the folder? If `list_files` returns an array, why do you `echo` the result? Would it not need to be turned into a string first? What security measures are in place? Please edit your question to include answers to **all** of those questions, even if the answer is "I don't know"

Comment: edited everything you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also check if that dir exists and loop through the list_files if they exist.

Since you asked for another idea to get those files: You can use the php function glob. It finds pathnames matching a pattern. You can find the [Glob PHP manual here.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();

$user_dirname = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.$current_user->user_login;
if ( ! file_exists( $user_dirname ) ) {
    wp_mkdir_p( $user_dirname );
    return;
}

foreach (glob($user_dirname  . "/*.mp3") as $filename) {
    echo $filename;
    echo do_shortcode('[audio src="/wp-content/uploads/'. $current_user->user_login . '/' . $filename . '"]');
}
```

Comment: i exactly tried this, but its returning an empty array (the code is in the OP)

Comment: get_home_url is the wrong function.  You need a file path for these functions, not the url where it lives. I'll edit my answer to add getting path dir.

Comment: This can be made more flexible by using `$upload_dir['baseurl']` instead of hardcoding the `wp-content/uploads` folder

Comment: Good catch, I added that after the original